# Custom Method Validation Error in Rails Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activerecord

I am new in Rails so please excuse this question. I recently ran into a problem and I would be grateful if someone could help finding the right solution.

I want to add this Custom Method to my validation. It should raise an error once the user submitd a start date that is past the end date

```
class Request < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates :start_date, :to_date, presence: true
    validates :checkin_date_cannot_be_in_the_past

    def checkin_date_cannot_be_in_the_past 
        if :date > :todate
        errors.add(:date, "can't be in the past") 
    end 
end
```

Unfortunately this Custom Method doesn't work for me like described in the [Active Record Validations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html) documentation and raises an error (syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end) in my Controller:

```
  def new
   @request = Request.new
  end
```

After spending some time researching I cant find the right solution so I hope maybe someone here could help?

Cheers

Rob

Comment: you need to call this method checkin_date_cannot_be_in_the_past for validation and what is date & todate here ?

Comment: sry mate that was just a typo (just edited). I actually do call checkin_date_cannot_be_in_the_past

Comment: you have missing one end for if condition that's why your are getting syntax error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this should be validate for calling custom validation not validates

```
class Request < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :start_date, :to_date, presence: true
  validate :checkin_date_cannot_be_in_the_past

  def checkin_date_cannot_be_in_the_past 
    errors.add(:date, "can't be in the past") if date > todate
  end 
end
```